# How to hide Command Prompt window after starting apache and mysql service?

Tags: windows, apache, batch-file

I have a batch file for running apache and mysql service in one go but this batch open a blank command prompt and does not close it.

```
@echo off
@start /b "" d:\hlwamp\apache24\bin\httpd.exe 
@start /b "" d:\hlwamp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe 
exit
```

How to automatically close the cmd after command execute. Or How do I just run the Batch file without seeing the prompt? The code works and starts both the services but the apache cmd is not closing.

Comment: You can use AutoIt: `GuiSetState(@SW_HIDE, $handleToCmdWindow)`.

Answer (score 0):

try this use exit 0

```
@echo off
@start /b "" d:\hlwamp\apache24\bin\httpd.exe 
@start /b "" d:\hlwamp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe 
exit 0
```